# How to call a function repeatedly with 5 seconds delay? (ASP.NET with C#)

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a some piece of code in Default.aspx.cs file which is written within Page_Load function like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //code stars here
    ...
    //code ends here   
}
```

What i want is that this piece of code will run continously with 5 seconds delay. How can I do this here?
Thank You.

Comment: Once your ASP.NET request has been handled all objects related to it are disposed. Your page object is no longer alive and cannot be made to continuously run a task every X seconds. It makes no sense to code something that will only slow down the handling of your requests...they should happen as fast as possible.

Comment: Actually I am working on chat system so i need to check after each 5 seconds for any incoming messages and i need to do this way. Please suggest me a way to do it (like any timing functions or whatever...)
I will appreciate your help.

Comment: You don't need to make this code run every 5 seconds on the server in one request. You need to request this code every 5 seconds from the client.

Comment: Alright, and how can i do this? Please can you provide sample code to request this code after each 5 seconds from client side?

Answer (score 3):

Looking at your comments I see your actually building a chat facility, which makes more sense regarding the continous requests every 5 seconds.

I would recommend using ASP.NET Web Methods and AJAX technology to achieve this.

Using `jQuery.ajax` you can make a request every 5 seconds in javascript to return new chat messages

Something like the following would be a good start for your javascript/jquery:

```
setInterval(function () {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "/Chat.asmx"
                            , type: "POST"
                            , contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8'
                            , data: '{ ConversationID: "' + ConversationID + '"}'
                            , dataType: 'json'
                            , success: function (data) {

                                //do something with data

                            }
                    });
                }, 5000);
```

Chat.asmx would then be your Web Method. Look into ASP.NET Web Methods for more info:

http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/

A quicker method, but not as recommended, would be to use `jQuery.load` where you could have the chat messages in a repeater on a standalone .aspx page and keep loading this into a div on your page like:

```
setInterval(function () {
     $(".chatmessages").load("ChatConversation.aspx?id=" + ConversationID);
}, 5000);
```

See [jQuery.load](http://api.jquery.com/load/) for more info on this

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If you can share some simple piece of code in above context than i will appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

As the others suggest, use ajax and get your data from the clietn every 5 seconds.
Here is a small sample which should get you started.

You need to include the jQuery javascript framework for this to work.

Clientside javascript:

```
// execute this on dom ready
$(document).ready(function () {    
    // call function getData every 5 seconds:
    setInterval("getData()", 5000);
});

// Call an asp PageMethod via an ajax call
function getData() {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      async: true,
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      url: "YourPage.aspx/GetData",
      // optional post some data 
      // data: JSON.stringify(data),          
      success: dataReceived
    });         
}

// callback function is called, when data is recevied
function dataReceived(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    // your data is in data.d

}
```

On the serverside you have to write a "page method" in your aspx page wich is a static method you can call by an ajax javascript call:

```
public class YourPage : Page
{

    [WebMethod]
    public static object GetData() {
        // return your data here
        return new {Data1 = ..., Data2 = ...};
    }
}
```

You can pass data to your page method by parameters. The names of the parameters have to match exactly the names of the json object properties you pass to $.ajax.

Answer (score 1):

From your edit, building a chat application would require more than just the page running a repeated task every 5 seconds.

For a simple chat, you could achieve this using AJAX and the `setInterval()` method in Javascript, but doing so could tie up all threads with an HTTP server such as Apache.

More prudent chats would make use of a distinct HTTP server created in many technologies, you might look into emerging technologies such as `socket.io` based on `node`.